# Meteor - React - FlowRouter how to redirect correctly based on device (PC or mobile)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, mobile, flow-router

I'm using Meteor, React and FlowRouter for my project, which will display differently based on PC or mobile.

Currently, my Router.js looks something like:

```
FlowRouter.route("/login", {
  name: "login",
  action(params) {
    mount(MyMainLayout, {
      content: <MyLoginComponent />
    });
  }
})
```

The problem now is I want the FlowRouter to redirect itself correctly based on PC or mobile: perhaps "/login" and "/sp/login" (I mean if users access the PC url by mobile phone, they will be redirected to SP url and vice versa, when they try to access SP url on their PC, the PC route will take place, instead)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: please use react router is better .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question here because it seems that nobody has an interest in this yet:

FlowRouter has its own `triggersEnter` feature, which will be useful here, and I will check the userAgent to determine if users access the site by their PC or mobile, then redirect them to correct landing pages.

My Router.js file will look something like this:

```
isMobile = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check; 
  // Note here that tablet will be treated as PC, too!
};

FlowRouter.route("/login", {
  name: "login_pc",
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    if(isMobile()){
      console.log('You are using mobile device');
      redirect('login_sp');
    }
  }],
  action(params) {
    mount(MyMainLayout, {
      content: <MyLoginComponent />
    });
  }
});

FlowRouter.route("/sp/login", {
  name: "login_sp",
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    if(!isMobile()){
      console.log('You are using PC');
      redirect('login_pc');
    }
  }],
  action(params) {
    mount(MyMainLayout, {
      content: <MyLoginComponentForSP />
    });
  }
});
```

Hope that this will be helpful for others later